# rn-sliding-up-panel not working when inside a DrawerNavigation in Android- React Native

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

I have a small app which should have a drawer menu in the side 
and a small Plus button which slides up a panel with more 4 buttons
something like this:

[image]

the app.js initiate a Switch navigator that have 2 screens, one for login and one for a Stack

the stack has the DrawerNavigation as the menu screen and other screens also.
and in the Drawer navigation there's some other screens:
the code below:

```
const SideMenuDrawer = createDrawerNavigator({
  Main: MainScreen,
  'Invite A Friend Screen': InviteAFriendScreen,
  About: AboutScreen,
  Schedule: ScheduleScreen,
  Groups: GroupsScreen
},
  {
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
      const { routeName } = navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index];
      return {
        headerTitle: routeName,
        headerTintColor: '#ffffff',
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#2F95D6',
          borderBottomColor: '#ffffff',
          borderBottomWidth: 3,
        },
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontSize: 18
        }
      }
    }
  }
);

const AppStack = createStackNavigator({
  MainScreen: SideMenuDrawer,
  PhotoScreen: PhotoScreen,
  DocumentScreen: DocumentScreen,
  AudioScreen: AudioScreen,
  GalleryScreen: GalleryScreen

},
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
      return {
        headerLeft: (
          <Icon
            name="md-menu"
            size={35}
            style={{ paddingLeft: 10 }}
            color="white"
            onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
          />
        )
      }
    }
  }
);



const AppContainer = createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    LoginSplashScreen: LoginSplashScreen,
    MainScreen: AppStack
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'MainScreen',
  }
));

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppContainer />
    )
  }
}
```

and the SlidingPanel is in the render() function of the **Menu screen**:

```
class MainScreen extends React.Component {
  state = {
    slideUpPanelvisible: false
  }

  render() {
    const window = Dimensions.get('window');
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const signedIn = global.signedIn;
    const name = global.name;
    const photoUrl = global.photoUrl;

    return (

      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={[styles.container]}  >
          <Text style={styles.header}>Welcome {name}</Text>
          <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: photoUrl }} />
        </View>

        <View style={styles.addButton}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => this.setState({ slideUpPanelvisible: true })} >
            <Icon name="add-circle" size={60} color='#0E2E49' />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>

        <SlidingUpPanel
          visible={this.state.slideUpPanelvisible}
          startCollapsed={true}
          draggableRange={{ top: window.height * 0.4, bottom: 0 }}
          onRequestClose={() => this.setState({ slideUpPanelvisible: false })}
          allowDragging={true}
        >
          <View style={styles.panelcontainer}>
            <Text style={styles.header}>Text inside the Sliding Panel </Text>

          </View>
        </SlidingUpPanel> 
      </View>

    )
  }
}
```

but the drawer doesnt show on android device (GEnymotion, android studio and a real device)
on an Iphone device it works great!

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In latest versions of react-navigation, you need to add react-native-gesture-handler and link it. Otherwise gestures will not work on Android.

https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler

```
  npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler
  react-native link react-native-gesture-handler
```

Also make sure things are linked properly(Sometimes auto-linking can fail). After this you can see that drawer is working in android.

Refer Documentation: https://kmagiera.github.io/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: I'm using expo, after doing these two lines and npm start  i get this message:
Unable to resolve "react-native-gesture-handler" from "node_modules\@react-navigation\native\src\Scrollables.js"